# fill custom form with object

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms

i have a simple form: `UserInfoForm()`.
when i first display the form to the user, i want it to be filled with data from a specific object of the `User` model.
can anyone give me a direction or an example?
thanks!

Comment: What do UserInfoForm and User classes extend?

Comment: UserInfoForm extends sfForm and User is a doctrine model. i'm looking for a solution like Tom gave me, but i get an error (read my comment on his post). thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd do it like this but it depends on how your UserInfoForm relates to the User object:

```
$user = Doctrine::getTable('User')->findOneById($user_id);
$this->form = new UserInfoForm($user);
```

*Edit: I'm assuming you're using Doctrine.*

Comment: i tried it but then i get:
Unknown record property / related component "_csrf_token" on "User".
it seems like it searches for _csrf_token column in User.
how do i "tell" the form that the csrf field isn't a column in User?

Comment: Hmm... that's strange, it shouldn't be happening. Are you rendering the token in the template only with "<?php echo $form['_csrf_token']->render() ?>" or are you doing something else with it?

Comment: If the problem persists, possibly something you could try is declaring the relevant fields in the form class: "$this->useFields(array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'));"

Comment: ... and also judging from the above comment you've made you need to ensure "class UserInfoForm extends BaseUserForm" in your form class declaration.

Comment: i dont want UserInfoForm to extend BaseUserForm because i want to make a form class from scratch, not overload the BaseUserForm.. also, i get the error from the action part, not from the template. i don't even render the form in the template and i still get the error.. is it because UserInfoForm extends sfForm and not BaseUserForm?

Comment: ok i think i will use the BaseUserForm as the class to extend from, since i found out (thanks to you) about the useFields method, which will help me alot. if you find a solution to my original question i'd still like to know, for the practice. thanks alot for your help!! :)

Comment: @Tamir: ok, glad to have been of help.